# How to query html node using class attribute?

Tags: yql

I am trying to query html data using YQL. 
I wanted to know how to perform query of a html node based on class attribute when the node has multiple classes, e.g:

```
<tr class='class1 class2'></tr>
```

This query works fine:

```
select * from html where url="http://soccernet.espn.go.com/scores" and
  xpath='//tr[@class="class1"]'
```

But when I try querying for `class2`, I've got empty result:

```
select * from html where url="http://soccernet.espn.go.com/scores" and
  xpath='//tr[@class="class2"]'
```

So basically I want to know how to query html nodes using YQL when the node has multiple class attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a better way - but this is how I tackle this problem when I come across it:

```
select * from html where url="http://soccernet.espn.go.com/scores" and xpath='//tr[contains(@class,"class2")]'
```

Comment: just be aware that this method will catch <tr class="class22"> as well as it still contains the string "class2". If you know that the tr will always be listed second on the element, use//tr[contains(@class," class2")] instead.